# Is there any application for a linear map from a lower dimensional space to a higher dimensional space?

Tags: linear-algebra

Does it make any sense to consider a linear map from a lower dimensional space to a higher dimensional space, i.e. matrix representations of linear maps $A$, where $A \in \mathbb{K}^{m \times n}, m>n$. Intuitively, I see that $A$ can only map to a linear subspace of $\mathbb{K}^m$. Do these maps ever pop up?

I guess it is pointless to consider this map right? We could simply align the basis in $\mathbb{K}^m$ to span the range of $A$ and then consider $A$ as a map from $\mathbb{K}^n$ to $\mathbb{K}^n$. Is this the right line of thinking?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It is a perfectly sensible thing to talk about, and there are plenty of uses for such maps. Take a look at [overdetermined systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overdetermined_system).

For another picture, think of how many different ways you can find linear maps of the plane $\Bbb R^2$ into $\Bbb R^3$. There are lots of different ways to "position" the plane in the volume.

Answer (score 1):

It's not pointless. There are some pretty reasonable ways to setup a non-trivial use for this.

Consider that we might 'perturb' $A$ by a little bit. That is, consider $A(\lambda): U \to \mathbb{K}^{m\times n}$ where $U$ is maybe a subset of complex numbers. Sure for any particular value of $\lambda$ we can pick an $n$ dimensional subspace, but as $\lambda$ changes so does that space. We might want to study how badly that space varies for small changes in $\lambda$.

So while your point is fair for any particular such matrix (as far as geometry goes), generalizing a little can create more interesting behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Here comes a list:

- Why not? It is a straightforward "generalization" with no problem at all.
- Surely it seems reasonable you to consider a smooth map from a manifold (read "space" if you are not familiar with the term) of lower dimension to one of higher dimension. For example, a curve is a map $\mathbb{R} \rightarrow X$. Its derivative is a linear map from a low dimension to a higher dimension.
- The inclusion of a subspace in another is a linear map, and a pretty natural one to consider.
- As said in another answer, overdetermined systems commonly appear in applications.
- etc